# Wordcount list in bash

Tags: bash, list, word-count

I am trying to count words in a list. This works :

```
echo "$list" | wc -w
```

But when I want to place this in a variable I get zero:

```
i="$lijst" | wc -w
echo i
```

Answer (score 1):

Put your code inside `$()` or backticks , so that the code get parsed.

```
i=$(echo "$list" | wc -w)
echo "$i"
```

Comment: you couldo do `i=$(wc -w <<< "$list")`